# MediaCodecInputStream: No buffer available... Google Glass live streaming

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, google-glass, wowza

I am trying to stream live video from Google Glass to a Wowza media server using the tutorial set out [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/), using the libstreaming library. This works fine on an Android phone but I am receiving an error when migrating the app over to Glass which is:

```
09-25 10:14:40.727 8377-8506/com.example.GlassApp V/MediaCodecInputStream: No buffer available...
```

The server is showing that the app is connecting fine but it seems to have trouble with video playback as the screen on the Glass itself remains grey as if it's trying to process and the `No buffer available` error is repeated in the logcat.

What is causing this error and why does it not show when streaming from a handset?

Comment: Hi! Have you been able to figure out how to solve "No buffer available"?

Comment: Yea I have but as it was so long ago I'm not quite sure what the cause was. I'll try and have a look and see if I've made any notes on what the problem was but I'm 90% sure the problem was actually the network I was using it on - the WiFi router in our office had approx. 300 devices registered to it and it just couldn't cope with transferring video data but I'll take a look and see if there was anything that I had done. Are you using Glass as your device?

Comment: No I'm actually not even using a router. I'm streaming directly over a wifi-direct connection from one android to another.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: any updates on this?